# How do I prevent Calendar from starting up when I log in to Mavericks?

Tags: calendar, macos, startup, login

Calendar starts up every time I boot up Mavericks. I cannot find a related option in its Preferences or in the Users and Groups login items page. How do I prevent Calendar from starting up when I log in to Mavericks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the calendar in the dock, select Options, and de-select Open at Login

Comment: I have this exact problem with Sierra - but the "Open at Login" option is *not* checked. :-/